# Why do current models use multiple normalization layers?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, batch-normalization

In most current models, the normalization layer is applied after each convolution layer. Many models use the block $\text{convolution} \rightarrow \text{batch normalization} \rightarrow \text{ReLU}$ repeatedly. But why do we need multiple [batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) layers? If we have a convolution layer that receives a normalized input, shouldn't it spit out a normalized output? Isn't it enough to place normalization layers only at the beginning of the model?

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that a normalized set of initial weights may not stay normalized as learning progresses; so given that we adjust weights proportionately according to their relative values and also when working on a subset of the learning data the model may become convinced that one subset of features is important and others not, this can result in the weights becoming unbalanced again. In the learning curve we may see this as a plateau, where the learning becomes convinced that a few features are much more important than they really are and fails to find new features that can contribute even more because tiny proportionate changes did not move them far, or quickly, enough into a noticeable range.

So when we re-sample from the database to get the next batch we need to be fully open to the possibility that the previous batch learning was too heavily biased towards its own favoured set. In effect we are trading accuracy for openness to new feature combinations, and at the same time assisting generalization.